# I can't remember my restriction password

Tags: password

If I can't remember the restriction password I can't reset all settings and watch videos on safari again.

Plz tell me how to reset my restriction password WITHOUT a computer or any apps.

I can't download any apps anymore until I reset all settings and can't do that cause don't remember restriction password. Plz tell me how to reset restriction password without computer or any apps thank u=>

Comment: So, your parents set a restriction code on your phone, and you're trying to get around it huh?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you won't be able to reset your Restrictions passcode without any apps or computer.

You would have to wipe or reset the phone through iTunes, or remotely erase your phone with Find My iPhone if it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

There was a way I found to get around this once (I forgot mine, too) and it involved extracting a .plist from a backup of your iPhone. In this .plist, there's a value called RestrictionsPasscodeKey and there's also RestrictionsPasscodeSalt (they're both something to do with encryption) and I found a Java app online where you could put these 2 values in and it would work through all the combinations of numbers until the code (combined with the salt) generated the original RestrictionsPasscodeKey.

My iPhone was jailbroken at the time so I could access the .plist from iFile, I have no idea how easy it is to extract it from a backup. Also, I was running iOS 8 at the time so I'm not sure whether this would work with iOS 9 (although the website I used worked for iOS 7 and 8). You would need a computer for this, though (unless you're jailbroken, you'll need still need a web browser though).

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately as of iOS 8 and later, iFile, iExplorer and similar software does not work as access to the file system has been restricted. So this is only accessible via jailbreaking or an iOS 7 or earlier device.

Additionally, iFile makes it relatively easy to extract a file from an iTunes backup.